# OpenGL pixel transfer inside GPU

Tags: opengl, copy, gpu, textures, pbo

I have been working with VR recently and encountered some OpenGL related problem.
The API i use for VR capture a video stream and write it to a texture, I, then, want to submit this texture to a headset. But there is an incompatibility in the API : the texture I get from the stream has an undefined internal format and cannot be submitted to the headset directly.

I am working on a workaround, for now, I have used a GPU -> CPU -> GPU transfer :
I read the first texture pixel (with glReadPixels) and write them into a buffer, then I use this buffer to create a texture with the correct format. This works fine but has some latencies due to data transfers.

I have been trying to do a direct GPU copy but failed :

- I tried using PBO but have problems with invalid operation (following http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html), here is the code with a invalid operation on glReadPixels

  ```
  // Initialization           
  glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);
  glGenTextures(1, &dstTexture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dstTexture);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

  // Copy to GPU
  glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo);
  glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, bufferSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);  // texture given by the API
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

  glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
  glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);
  glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, bufferSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_READ);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dstTexture);

          glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
  ```
- I tried using FBO but encountered pointer exceptions.
- glCopyImageSubData does not work because the first texture internal format is not recognised.

What are the steps to do a direct GPU copy?

Comment: Use a PBO.....?

Comment: Looks like you don't want to copy it, you want to convert it. Do a shader pass for that.